# How do I build ffmpeg including x264 library for android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libx264

Lots of question and answer available on the ffmpeg and android. But I did not get thing that directly address ffmpeg building with x264 library.

Actually I want to make a movie from some still images in android.

Still do not get any solution to resolve this problem. Some of the forum told that it can be do using ffmpeg. If I build ffmpeg after downloading from "http://bambuser.com/opensource", it works fine to decode a video file. But it does not get any codec while it try to encode still image into movie.

That's why I try to use x264 as encoding library with ffmpeg. While I try to build it with ffmpeg it returns error.

Could you please provide any detail step by step guide line to build ffmpeg with x264 library in windows or mac for android?

If any one knows anything other that can be used to make movie from still images in android please tell me the way. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your kind response.

Answer (score 3):

I made a tutorial on how to build `ffmpeg` and `x264` for `android`:
http://db.tt/TjMqIF3u

You can also download the zip file containing the files you need to make an application on `android` and also an executable of lastest `ffmpeg` to run on `android`.
PS: you might need Cygwin to compile `ffmpeg` in Windows.